# Google OAuth2 how to signin with full account access?

Tags: google-oauth

I want to develop a tool to access user's google info. it requires the full account access, **I found a app can request for the permission**. But I cannot find the scope in [OAuth 2.0 Scopes for Google APIs](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/googlescopes).

How could I do this? what is the full account access scope?
I develop this tool for myself, not would be used by others.

[image]

Comment: Isn't this app from Google by any chance? What's the name?

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know there is not any scope that can request full access like you want. And my guess is that even if it existed before it was removed due to obvious security reasons. I have also searched for some examples of this scope but I could not find any.

In other words, if I were you I would use multiple scopes for each specific task I need to implement. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 2):

It can be some undocumented flow, maybe with `https://www.google.com/accounts/OAuthLogin` scope. Maybe it is an old screenshot and app from the screenshot was using now deprecated OAuth 1.0.

There was one issue, which seems to be similar: https://searchsecurity.techtarget.com/news/450300257/Pokemon-GO-reveals-full-account-access-flaw-for-Google-authentication